# Anchor not working – can't find why

Tags: html, anchor

Here

https://glueckundsegen.de/stammbuch/

(I've included the url, since I expect that maybe the problem is not in the code snippets below)

is a red button saying "Mehr erfahren" thats like "more ...". The button is basically a link:

```
<a href="https://glueckundsegen.de/stammbuch/#mehr" target="_blank">
  <div  id="gus--details" class="gus--details">
  Mehr erfahren ...
  </div>
</a>
```

And its intended to target an anchor at the headline "Unsere Stammbücher: Durchdacht in allen Details":

```
<hr />
<p><a id="mehr"></a>&nbsp;</p>
<h2 class="headone">Unsere Stammb&uuml;cher: Durchdacht in allen Details</h2>
```

Intended behaviour is, to open a new window and jump down to that anchor. I thought this is pretty simple and bulletproof stuff but it doesn't work for some reason.

It works well in firefox 66 Developer Edition but fails reproducibly in Safari 12.0.2 and most of the time in Chrome 71.0.3578.98

I don't have any idea why? Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#mehr">
<div  id="gus--details" class="gus--details">
Mehr erfahren ...
</div>
</a>
```

*without target _blank*

**example**: http://jsfiddle.net/5eztgq3p/

Comment: but why? So it´s not possible to open a page in a new window and jump to the anchor?

Comment: try add attr:  target="new"

Answer (score 0):

Your href

```
href="https://glueckundsegen.de/stammbuch/#mehr"
```

is slightly wrong.  Remove the last `/` leaving

```
href="https://glueckundsegen.de/stammbuch#mehr"
```

The url you are using indicates a page within the stammbuch folder at https://glueckundsegen.de